# Telebot Python нужно создать функцию для handler

Tags: python, telebot

Безопасность банка
Саша создал телеграм бота для банка, чтобы предупреждать пользователей о злоумышленниках, при отправке данных карт, и удалять сообщение с данными. Если пользователь отправил одно из "ключевых" слов, то, возможно, в сообщении есть данные от банковской карты. Помогите Саше написать функцию findkeywords, которую он вставит в @bot.message_handler(), чтобы проверять сообщения на ключевые слова и удалять сообщения с данными от карт.

Что вам нужно сделать:

Функция должна выводить True если слова есть и False если их нет.
Функция не должна быть зависимой от регистра

Comment: Опишите,  пожалуйста, в каком виде должны подаваться данные в функцию.

Comment: В виде строки через input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-видимому, как-то так. Здесь `message_text` нужно вытащить из сообщения, которое прислал боту пользователь.

```
words = ['безопасность', 'карта', 'номер', 'счёт']
message_text = 'Здравствуйте! Нас интересует Ваша безопасность. Продектуйте, пожалуйста НоМер счёТА.'
text = message_text.lower()

for word in words:
    if word in text: 
        return True

return False
```

Comment: спасибо, большое!